# Need some pointers on use of jQueryUI themes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I just started looking into the use of jQuery UI. What I would like to know is if people are using this to theme whole web sites. I like the idea of doing this but I am not sure if it's a good way to go and also where to start. Just for an example I have tables on my web site. I'd like to theme these but I am not sure where to start. I found the following:

```
.ui-widget: Class to be applied on outer container of all widgets. Applies font family and font size to widget. Also applies same family and 1em font size to child form elements specifically, to combat inheritance issues in Win browsers.
.ui-widget-header: Class to be applied to header containers. Applies header container styles to an element and its child text, links, and icons.
.ui-widget-content: Class to be applied to content containers. Applies content container styles to an element and its child text, links, and icons. (can be applied to parent or sibling of header)
```

Would I be on the right track if I assigned the `.ui-widget` to the table?  Anyone have an example of how they have themed a table or even how they themed the background color of the web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [ThemeRoller application](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). Look at the HTML source of the site and check which styles they apply to the HTML components. The datepicker, for instance, uses a table inside and has assigend the `ui-datepicker-calendar` class.

UPDATE:

Look at the source code using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Answer (score 2):

I think the decision depends mostly on the project and if the classes and styles the jqueryui provides are sufficient for your project. In the end, you will always have to extend the jqueryui to defere your page style from it. Most commonly, though, you'd rather make the jqueryui adapt to your site's style, not the other way around.